# Linker error using restbed

Tags: c++, linker, cmake, restbed

so, i'm trying to compile my program which has restbed as dependency.
I already compiled restbed with the following command:

```
cmake -DBUILD_TESTS=NO -DBUILD_SSL=YES -DBUILD_SHARED=NO
make -j4 install
```

Compiling restbed does not result in any errors.

Now the Problem:

I'm using the example source code from here: https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed

This is my CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project(FDRService CXX)

# Setup
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR "./build")
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

# FD Variables
set(FDRService_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set(FDRService_VERSION_MINOR 0)

set(FDRService_INCLUDE_DIR "./include")
set(FDRService_SOURCE_DIR "./src")

# RestBED
set(RESTBED_ROOT "dependency/restbed/distribution")
set(RESTBED_INCLUDE_DIR "${RESTBED_ROOT}/include")
set(RESTBED_LIBRARY_DIR "${RESTBED_ROOT}/library")

# find all libraries
file(GLOB_RECURSE RESTBED_LIBRARY_FILES
    "${RESTBED_LIBRARY_DIR}/*.a"
)

include_directories(${RESTBED_INCLUDE_DIR})

# find project source files
file(GLOB_RECURSE FDRService_FILES
    "${FDRService_INCLUDE_DIR}/*.h"
    "${FDRService_INCLUDE_DIR}/*.hpp"
    "${FDRService_SOURCE_DIR}/*.c"
    "${FDRService_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp"
)

add_executable(FDRService ${FDRService_FILES})
target_link_libraries(FDRService ${RESTBED_LIBRARY_FILES})
```

When i try to compile my project i get the following linker errors:

http://pastebin.com/hXPmAV2W (too much text for StackOverflow...)

My guess is that the OpenSSL library is not linked into the static .a file of restbed, but i put -DBUILD_SSL in the build command.

I hope anyone of you can help me with this problem. It's driving me crazy.

If you need more information, just tell me and i'll edit this post.

Comment: "My guess". This sounds like a 100% sure bet. Are you sure you know what `-DBUILD_SSL` does?

Comment: The linker doesn't find those symbols, because the libraries where they reside in were not specified to it. On quick look over the errors, seem like you have to pass `-lpthread -lcrypto -lssl` to the linker (of course the 3 libraries should be in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`). Not sure how to translate that in "_cmake_ syntax" though.

Comment: Well, i didn't think of adding those extra libraries, stupid me... Thanks anyway. it workes now

Comment: Sorry about the delay in responding to this question. @CristiFati is correct in his statement.  You can find the cmake modules we use below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the following cmake modules to locate the necessary dependencies for projects reliant on Restbed.

**Findrestbed.cmake**

```
find_path( restbed_SOURCE CMakeLists.txt HINTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/restbed" )

if ( restbed_SOURCE )
    set( restbed_FOUND TRUE )
    set( restbed_BUILD "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/restbed_build" )
    set( restbed_DISTRIBUTION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/distribution" )

    include( ExternalProject )
    ExternalProject_Add( restbed SOURCE_DIR ${restbed_SOURCE}
                         PREFIX restbed_build
                         INSTALL_DIR ${restbed_DISTRIBUTION}
                         CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${restbed_DISTRIBUTION} -DBUILD_SSL=${BUILD_SSL} -DBUILD_SHARED=NO )

    set( restbed_INCLUDE "${restbed_DISTRIBUTION}/include" )
    set( restbed_LIBRARY "${restbed_DISTRIBUTION}/library/${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX}restbed${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}" )

    message( STATUS "${Green}Found Restbed include at: ${restbed_SOURCE}${Reset}" )
else ( )
    message( FATAL_ERROR "${Red}Failed to locate Restbed dependency.${Reset}" )
endif ( )
```

**Findopenssl.cmake**

```
find_library( ssl_LIBRARY ssl ssleay32 HINTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/restbed/dependency/openssl/out32dll" "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/restbed/dependency/openssl" "/usr/lib" "/usr/local/lib" "/opt/local/lib" )
find_library( crypto_LIBRARY crypto libeay32 HINTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/restbed/dependency/openssl/out32dll" "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/restbed/dependency/openssl" "/usr/lib" "/usr/local/lib" "/opt/local/lib" )
find_path( ssl_INCLUDE openssl/ssl.h HINTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/restbed/dependency/openssl/inc32" "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/restbed/dependency/openssl/include" "/usr/include" "/usr/local/include" "/opt/local/include" )

if ( ssl_INCLUDE AND ssl_LIBRARY AND crypto_LIBRARY )
    set( OPENSSL_FOUND TRUE )
    add_definitions( -DBUILD_SSL=TRUE )

    if ( APPLE AND BUILD_SSL )
        set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-deprecated-declarations" )
    endif( )

    message( STATUS "${Green}Found OpenSSL library at: ${ssl_LIBRARY}${Reset}" )
    message( STATUS "${Green}Found OpenSSL include at: ${ssl_INCLUDE}${Reset}" )
    message( STATUS "${Green}Found Crypto library at: ${crypto_LIBRARY}${Reset}" )
else ( )
    message( FATAL_ERROR "${Red}Failed to locate OpenSSL dependency. see dependency/restbed/dependency/openssl; ./config shared; make all${Reset}" )
endif ( )
```

You can see an example of this in action at the [RestQ GIT repository](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restq).